# Possible memory leak in Square/Picasso for Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, picasso

I am part of a team developing a commercial media app.  Part of the functionality is to allow the user to customise a ViewGroup montage of ImageViews with their own images retrieved either from Gallery or direct from Camera.  I am using the following Picasso call to do this:

```
    mPicasso.load(uri)
            .resize(newWidth, newHeight)
            .into(container);
```

where mPicasso is `Picasso.with(appContext())` and newWidth and newHeight are dimensions calculated from the source height and width such that aspect ratio is maintained and the resulting image is 1MP. Typically, the sources are between 8 and 16MP.

If I have a montage of say, eight ImageViews, and I keep adding images to each one in turn, the app eventually crashes. Device only has so much memory, right? Eventually if you keep adding infinite images you're going to run out. What really concerns me, however, is that the app will crash half-way through *replacing* the eight images. To be clear, you've added your eight images and you've gone back to the top and started replacing those images with different ones and you get to roughly the fourth before the crash.

I would have expected that once an image has been replaced, the old one would be cleaned up.  I can fix this by reducing the max size down to 100KP but the problem with that is I imagine I am just delaying the crash.  Furthermore, the user has the ability to zoom the image and with such a low resolution, it starts to look knarly quite quickly.

I have posted the crash log here:-
https://gist.github.com/mylesbennett/452c992f6912039ea62d
because it's too long to paste direcly in stackoverflow.

Any suggestions of workarounds/ fixes etc. would be greatly appreciated.

(the crash point in `TemplateImageView.isScaleInitialised` is where the app is attempting to allocate memory to a nine-value float array:

```
float[] values = new float[9];
```

so I am guessing that this is just the straw that broke the camel's back)